# I have a problem installing a virtual environment for python on VScode

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXOMx.png)
[IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6zg6.png)

IMAGE 1 is from my system showing me that I've installed sklearn under venv but when I run it on vscode it shows me IMAGE 2 stating that it isn't installed under venv... I only have this YouTube video as reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyQM70vi7V8 but it's for OS and I'm running on windows and this is basically the last step and I'm stuck

I've created a kernel named venv
I've sucessfully activated it and now I'm trying to install the sklearn which installed on my system and on vscode but when I run it doesnt show...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot does not clearly show the location of the **sklearn** package, but your error clearly shows that the environment you are using does not have the **sklearn** package.

The python interpreter version currently used will be displayed in the lower right corner of vscode,

[image]

click on it and select the *correct* interpreter (*the one containing the **sklearn** package*) in the ***Select Interpreter*** panel.

[image]

You can also use the following code to output the current python interpreter path, and then use the full path command to install the **sklearn** package for it.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

[image]